# Aptitude solutions vs running apt install. Why does aptitude have so many solutions and apt have none?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, apt

I was reinstalling the nvidia cuda drivers the other day with aptitude. The solutions it suggested were many, over a hundred of them, the vast majority of which were to leave the new package that I selected in an uninstalled state.

Using apt, it selected the packages without presenting any other alternatives and installed it without fuss.

The question is, why is there a discrepancy between aptitude and apt? Shouldn't they both be privy to the same solution sets?

Comment: Doesn't sound like a programming question to me.